# How to extract information from html text with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I might have a document with the following information:

```
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<p>A person name</p>
<p><i>Works somewhere, in some country</i></p>
<p>Grab this text as well</p>
```

This block will basically repeat x amount of times. I need to extract this information. However, the number of `<p> tags` will vary so could be 7 separate ones before the `h1 tag` appears again. I am using `beautifulsoup` as well to help with this.

I can extract this data but cannot make a rule so that for every `h1 tag` extract the x number of tags after that until it is a `h1 tag` again.

So every time a h1 tag appears this is a new record.

Hope this makes sense thanks!

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Hi, have you tried BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: yes I am using beautifulsoup but cannot make a rule, so that it extracts all the p tags after every h1 tag appears

Answer (score 0):

What sort of data structure are you hoping to store this in?

You could use the python `.split()` function and split by `"<h1>"`, which would give you something that looks like this:

```
text = """<h1>Some Text</h1>
       <p>A person name</p>
       <p><i>Works somewhere, in some country</i></p>
       <p>Grab this text as well</p>
       <h1>Some More Text</h1>
       <p>Grab this</p>"""

textChunks = text.split("<h1>")
```

Then textChunks would look something like

```
["""Some Text</h1>
       <p>A person name</p>
       <p><i>Works somewhere, in some country</i></p>
       <p>Grab this text as well</p>""",
 """Some More Text</h1>
       <p>Grab this</p>"""]
```

And you can treat each separate chunk differently by looping through the array, or using beautifulsoup.